# Multiple iframe embeds using Youtube Player API

Tags: api, iframe, youtube, embed

The situation:

- I have a page with links to youtube videos
- When a link gets clicked a new iframe is loaded into the page using javascript (without reloading) (see http://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)
- After the video finishes, or the user chooses to close it earlier, I call player.destroy() and the player is removed from the DOM.

All this is working like it should. But then, after the video is removed, it doesn't load up a second iframe anymore. Maybe something needs to be reset before it can load a new video (some javascript object, event listeners, etc)? What can I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it! Only with the first video the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function is called by the youtube API, because after that the `IframeAPI` remains ready.

So, if you want the first video to run, you have to use `new YT.Player()` in the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function. With the second and beyond you can immediately use `new YT.Player()`.